# How do you make the TreeView.SelectedNode property nulled without nulling the current node in the SelectedNode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

If `TreeView.SelectedNode = null` is used, would it also null the node object on the SelectedNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be confusing *references* and *objects*. You can have a `null`-reference (which refers to no object at all), but there is no such thing as  a `null`-object in C#.

If on the other hand, you are concerned that setting the `SelectedNode` property to `null` will evict the *currently* selected node from the `TreeView`, this is not the case - that node will simply be *unselected*.

**EDIT**: Perhaps you are concerned that the values of *other* variables that hold references to the currently-selected node will be set to `null` should the `SelectedNode` property be set to `null`. This is not the case either:

```
TreeView treeView = ...

TreeNode node = new TreeNode();    
treeView.Nodes.Add(node);

treeView.SelectedNode = node;

treeView.SelectedNode = null; 
bool isNodeNull = (node == null); // false
```

Comment: its weird, I'm using .NET Framework 4, and if I try something like myTreeView.SelectedNode = null  then it states " cannot be assigned to -- it is read-only"

Answer (score 2):

**No.** The `SelectedNode` property refers only to the node that is currently selected, so you can set it to `null` without "nulling the node object" itself. It will simply de-select whatever node is currently selected in the `TreeView` control.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx):

> If no TreeNode is currently selected, the SelectedNode property is Nothing.

Comment: You should mean *null*. *Nothing* in VB.NET ;)

Comment: @tsocks: Yes. But it's a quote from the documentation, so I didn't change it. The asker already knows they should set it to `null`, and I mentioned that at the beginning of my answer as well.